# Retrieving column data from inner join ambiguous column name

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this code which executes a search on about 30-40 columns using a programatically generated query on a join of 11 tables so naturally surrogate keys can show up a few times.
the results of the search are then grouped by tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk to prevent double ups in the final search results screen, and I am up to retrieving data from related tables (most one to many).

the code here is supposed to loop through the grouped results, retrieve any badge fields associated with that sub model, concatenate the badges together into one string and echo them after the make and model something like "subaru forrester xs ltd"
I get make and model but nothing else at point A and nothing at point B. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the fact that I am referring to "tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk" rather than for example "model_name". any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $badge_result_list = mysql_query("select badge from tbl_badge where sub_model_sk = {$row['tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk']}");
            $badge_str='';
            while ($badge_result = mysql_fetch_array($badge_result_list)) {
                $badge_str.=$badge_result;
            }
            echo $row['tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk'];  //<<<<<point B
            echo "<div class=\"top\" rel=\"{$div_count_id}\">{$row['manufacturer_name']} {$row['model_name']} {$badge_str}</div>";  //<<<<<point A
            echo "<div class=\"mid\" id=\"mid{$div_count_id}\" style=\"display: none;\">";
            echo $row['tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk'];
            echo "</div>";

            $div_count_id++;
        }
```

Comment: php has no concept of "joins" - that's an SQL thing, and you're not going any joins in your query.

Comment: read this tutorial about join http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I am aware that php doesn't do the joining if that's what you mean 
the $result array comes from
select * from tbl_sub_model inner join tbl_model on tbl_sub_model.model_sk=tbl_model.model_sk inner join tbl_manufacturer_lookup on tbl_model.manufacturer_sk=tbl_manufacturer_lookup.manufacturer_sk left join tbl_sub_model_feature on tbl_sub_model_feature.sub_model_sk=tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk.......... where UPPER(tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk) like '%SUBA%' or UPPER(tbl_sub_model.oldid) like '%SUBA%' or UPPER(tbl_sub_model.variant) like '%SUBA%'.........
group by tbl_sub_model.sub_model_sk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use print_r($row); to see what rows are available in your query, then you know what key to use to get the info you want.

Comment: ok, so what gives? I get "Array ( [0] => 89 [sub_model_sk] => 89 [1] => SFRST97AB [oldid] => SFRST97AB [2] => 584 [model_sk] => 584 [3] => [gen_sk] => [4] => 1997 [sub_model_year] => 1997...................." printed out on the page under each record and sub_model_sk only appears once at the start, despite the fact that my quere is select * from...inner join...
putting the same query into mysql workbench returns multiple sub_model_sk. is php smart enough to edit out repeats?

Comment: An associative array can't have two elements with the same key. And `mysql_fetch_array` just uss the unqualified column name as the key. You should use column aliases to ensure that the names are unique.